# SQl how i can convert GMT string to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following date: Fri, 24 Jun 2022 16:44:39 GMT, how can I convert it in SQL Server to yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss format?

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 3):

Try_convert() with a substring()

```
Select try_convert(datetime,substring('Fri, 24 Jun 2022 16:44:39 GMT',5,21))
```

**Results**

```
2022-06-24 16:44:39.000
```

Comment: Beat me by about 12 seconds. :-) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fa05573ef60910991baf4e7412adbe70

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, an additional question, is there any way to subtract 5 hours from that result???

Comment: @willysepulveda time zone conversion is a separate issue from formatting, also is it possible that it's always 5 hours? Are you converting to a time zone that does not observe DST/summer time?

Comment: thanks again, so the idea is to convert to a time zone that doesn't respect daylight saving time/DST

Comment: @willysepulveda Then just use `DATEADD(HOUR, -5, <the result>)`.